About tomatoes pigments, why red tomatoes rather than yellow ones
How the first tomatoes (yellow) that arrived in Europe turned from yellow to red ?
I know the yellow pigment is xantophylle and the red one is lycopene, but my question is, was it an adaptation of the plant to new soil conditions, temperatures or insects ? Or just a natural random mutation like, and it probably already happened in America ?
Bonus question:
Why did Europeans stopped to eat yellow tomates, and prefered red ones, was It because they though the fruit color was aphrodisiac ? And now why do even American tomatoes are red.
(They were called pommodoro in Italian, pomme d'or or pomme d'amour in French, " mala aurea " in Latin, and " love apple" in English.)

Probably due to a natural genetic mutation amplified by human cultural preferences and selective breeding practices.
Europeans may have preferentially selected and cultivated the red varieties for a few reasons:

The red colour was novel and visually striking compared to
yellow/orange fruits more common in Europe.
There was a belief that the deeper red colour indicated more ripeness.
Different (arguably better?) flavour – yellow = less acidic + milder.
Some cultures associated the vibrant red colour with love/fertility,
lending to names like the French "pomme d'amour”.

